# Swift - dynamically change size of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to dynamically change frame of UIButton, but it doesn't work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

@IBAction func btn_move2_touchupinside(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
           button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
}
```

I'm guessing that I should reload button after frame is changed.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Does the button have any text? Have you put a breakpoint on this function to ensure it executes?

Comment: There would be no need to reload button after changing frame, changing frame will take care of it

Comment: @Jay Morgan, yes, function executes and button is initialized in storyboard

Answer (score 2):

Auto Layout is preventing you from updating your button's frame.  Here are 3 different ways you can  make this work from easiest to set up to hardest:

1. Turn off Auto Layout.  In Interface Builder, click on your View Controller.  Then in the *File Inspector* on the far right, uncheck *Use Auto Layout*.
2. Define your button programmatically in `ViewDidLoad`:

   ```
   let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
   button.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)
   button.addTarget(self, action: "btn_move2_touchupinside:forEvent:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   button.setTitle("New Button", forState: .Normal)
   self.view.addSubview(button)
   ```
3. Set up 4 constraints for your button (horizontal offset from superview leading margin, vertical offset from top layout guide, width, and height).  Set up `@IBOutlets` for these constraints and then update their `constant` properties in code.

Comment: but, without auto layout I will not be able to make my app adaptive to different devices. Is there any other ways?

Comment: My answer provided 3 separate ways you could deal with this. Only the first involves turning off Auto Layout. Look at the 3rd suggestion. I can go into more detail on this one if you like. Do you have just one button you want to change or many? Do you want to grow it, or move it as well?

Comment: Try the 2nd suggestion.  Just cut and paste the provided code into `viewDidLoad` to create your button.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code will work fine:

```
button.layer.frame = newFrame
```

Or you will need to reset the center of the button:

```
button.frame = newFrame
button.center = newCenter
```