# How to change button frame in customTableViewCell in tableViewCellForRowAtIndex

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, frame

I want to make my button a bit wider, here is the code I'm trying to make work:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondItemTableCell") as! SecondItemTableViewCell
    cell.docentBtn.setTitle(data[subjects[indexPath.section]]![indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    println(cell.docentBtn.frame)
    cell.docentBtn.frame = CGRectMake(cell.docentBtn.frame.origin.x, cell.docentBtn.frame.origin.y, cell.docentBtn.frame.width + 20.0, cell.docentBtn.frame.height)
    cell.docentBtn.layer.cornerRadius = cell.docentBtn.frame.height / 2
    cell.docentBtn.clipsToBounds = true
    println(cell.docentBtn.frame)
    return cell
}
```

Output:

> (8.0, 5.0, 49.0, 34.0)
>   (8.0, 5.0, 69.0, 34.0)

But visually nothing changed. Can someone help me what is wrong?

Comment: your question is a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205771/swift-dynamically-change-size-of-uibutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding buttons width constraint to my custom cell class and then update its value in cellForRowAtIndex.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondItemTableCell") as! SecondItemTableViewCell
    cell.docentBtn.setTitle(data[subjects[indexPath.section]]![indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.docentBtnWidth.constant = cell.docentBtn.frame.width + 25.0
    cell.docentBtn.layer.cornerRadius = cell.docentBtn.frame.height / 2
    cell.docentBtn.clipsToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```